# Github library categories

Tags: github

I was wondering is if there any way to list out all the public library projects for a specific category (like android or java etc..) on github? samething like tags we have on stackoverflow. 
I did some search on that but that didn't lead me anywhere. All I found is one community on google+ of various developers posting their library projects with the hyper-link to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub provides a [`Search API`](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/) for developers. I invite you to read the documentation and the possible queries you might perform.

As the documentation explains if you wanted to search for popular `Tetris` repositories written in `Assembly`, your query might look like this:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc
```